# Apply typeclass constraint to inner type of another typeclass

Tags: haskell, types, type-constraints

Consider this function:

```
f :: Num a0 => [a0] -> Int
f = -- Let's leave open what we actually do here.
```

We want to generalize this function to work not only on lists, but also on `Set a`, `IntSet a` and others. Basically, we want this function to be defined for any [`MonoTraversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html) that contains `Num` elements in it.

Here comes the problem: We need to combine the `MonoTraversable` constraint:

```
f :: MonoTraversable a1 => a1 -> Int
```

with the `Num` constraint:

```
f :: Num a0 => [a0] -> Int
```

However, `MonoTraversable` is a typeclass, therefore this can't work (several variants of this is what I tried):

```
f :: Num a0 => MonoTraversable a0 -> Int
```

From hours of researching I guess it's possible to somehow use `RankNTypes` (specifically, a rank 2 polymorphism) for this purpose.

Another failed attempt that might display what I'm aiming for:

```
f :: Num a0, MonoTraversable a1 => a0 a1 -> Int
```

However, I just can't find any way how to do it even close to properly. Using GHC extensions is fine for me.

Comment: Have you considered using classes and instances?

Comment: `(MonoTraversable a0, Num (Element a0)) => a0 -> Int`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(MonoTraversable a0, Num (Element a0)) => a0 -> Int` looks like it ought to work, qualifying the type family instance.

Comment: This typechecks at the very least, but `f = undefined` doesn't prove much.  Looks like you need the `FlexibleContexts` extension for it as well.

Comment: I would expect so, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You actually need `FlexibleContexts`, but this is not an issue in my usecase. Would you say the fact that `Element` is a type family is what makes the problem solvable the way you did it?